# Drupal 7 select optgroup and allow multiple selections

Tags: drupal-7, html-select, optgroup

I am using drupal 7 and need a form that provides a select box with optgroups and allows the user to select multiple items.

I can create the #options array along with optgroup by using

```
array(
   ['Option Group 1']=>array(
      [1]=>'First Item',
      [2]=>'Second Item',
   ),
   ['Option Group 2']=>array(
      [3]=>'Third Item',
   ),
);
```

but if I then set

```
'#multiple'=>TRUE
```

I just get a select full of checkboxes with array() as the list item title

If I set

```
  '#attributes'=>array('multiple'=>'multiple')
```

The form looks correct but drupal does not recognise any of my selections and sends me back to the form saying I need to select an option from the list.